# EmberJs router with two route segments with the same name - possible?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

Given the following router implementation:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('foo', function() { // URL /foo
        this.resource('bars', function() { //URL /foo/bars
            this.route('bar', { path: '/:bar_id', }); //URL /foo/bars/123
        });
    });

    this.route('bars'); //URL /bars
```

... I would like to be able to have them accessible at the URLs indicated in the comments on each line.

The problem occurs because `bars` appears twice;
when this happens, when the URL `/foo/bars` is loaded,
the template and controller for `/bars` is are rendered within the outlet of `/foo`.

Is there a way around this, that allows me to maintain the URLs as they are?

(that is for `bars` to be present in both `/foo/bars` and `/bars`)

---

UPDATE:

Here's the implemented solution, based on [@blessenm's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25115542/194982):

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('foo', function() { // URL /foo
        this.resource('foo-bars', { path: 'bars' }, function() { //URL /foo/bars
            this.route('bar', { path: '/:bar_id', }); //URL /foo/bars/123
        });
    });

    this.route('bars'); //URL /bars
```

For this to work, the file paths, in which various Ember units are saved, needs to be modified accordingly:

- `app/{controllers,routes/templates}/foo-bars.{js,hbs}`
- `app/{controllers,routes/templates}/foo-bars/bar.{js,hbs}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `this.resource` you are creating a new namespace. This will interfere with the last route specified. So for the last route to work, you will need to change its name and specify the `path` property to get the url you want. The updated code will look like

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('foo', function() { // URL /foo
    this.resource('bars', function() { //URL /foo/bars
      this.route('bar', { //URL /foo/bars/123
        path: '/:bar_id',
      });
    });
  });

  this.route('bars-root', {path: 'bar'});
});
```

**[Here is a working bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/saziku/1/edit)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25113919/194982) with the implemented solution, along with the required changes to the file paths.